# Timedelta and datetime data ( TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe with variable start time values as `0 days 04:52:00` and end time as `0 days 08:54:00` and a third variable AT.

```
ST  ET  AT
0 days 04:52:00 0 days 08:54:00 1198
0 days 04:54:00 0 days 08:59:00 1195
0 days 04:56:00 0 days 10:16:00 1120
0 days 04:57:00 1 days 01:33:00 204
0 days 04:57:00 0 days 09:15:00 1182
0 days 05:02:00 0 days 08:53:00 1209
0 days 05:04:00 0 days 20:23:00 521
```

The datatypes of the three variables on enquiry obtained is `pandas.core.series.Series`

```
type(df['ST'])
type(df['ET'])
type(df['AT'])

df.to_dict()
{'ST': {0: '0 days 04:52:00',
  1: '0 days 04:54:00',
  2: '0 days 04:56:00',
  3: '0 days 04:57:00',
  4: '0 days 04:57:00',
  5: '0 days 05:02:00',
  6: '0 days 05:04:00'},
 'ET': {0: '0 days 08:54:00',
  1: '0 days 08:59:00',
  2: '0 days 10:16:00',
  3: '1 days 01:33:00',
  4: '0 days 09:15:00',
  5: '0 days 08:53:00',
  6: '0 days 20:23:00'},
 'AT': {0: 1198, 1: 1195, 2: 1120, 3: 204, 4: 1182, 5: 1209, 6: 521}}
```

I wanted to extract the hours, minutes, and seconds value from ST and ET and use it in datetime format.

```
df['hst']= df['ST'].dt.components['hours'].astype(int)
df['mst']= df['ST'].dt.components['minutes'].astype(int)
df['sst']= df['ST'].dt.components['seconds'].astype(int)
df['het']= df['ET'].dt.components['hours'].astype(int)
df['met']= df['ET'].dt.components['minutes'].astype(int)
df['set']= df['ET'].dt.components['seconds'].astype(int)
```

However, even after using `.astype(int)` the datatype of `df['hst'], df['mst'], df['sst'], df['het'], df['met'], and df['set']` is still `pandas.core.series.Series`

I receive the error on executing the code below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = datetime(2021,7,11,df['hst'],df['mst'],df['sst'])
```

Error: `cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

Comment: Will you please add some sample code creating your dataframe to the question? I can't figure out how to get a sample dataframe like what you have. e.g. the return value of `df.to_dict()`

Comment: @user17242583 Any answers?

Comment: df.apply(lambda x: datetime(2021,7,11,x['hst'],x['mst'],x['sst']), axis=1)  you are passing the series (the entire column) and pandas doesn't know what to do with it. using apply and writing the function like operates on each row

Comment: "*datatypes of the three variables on enquiry obtained is pandas.core.series.Series*" - to clarify, a DataFrame combines multiple pandas.Series along a common axis. Each Series ("column" of the DataFrame) holds elements of certain data types, for example integer or timedelta (data types can also be mixed within a Series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the durations (pd.Series of type timedelta) to a reference date to get datetime columns:

```
# make sure the data type of the elements is timedelta:
df['ST'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['ST'])
df['ET'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['ET'])

# we need a reference date to which we can add the durations
ref_date = pd.Timestamp("2021-07-11")

df['start'] = ref_date + df['ST']
df['end'] = ref_date + df['ET']

df.head()
               ST              ET    AT               start                 end
0 0 days 04:52:00 0 days 08:54:00  1198 2021-07-11 04:52:00 2021-07-11 08:54:00
1 0 days 04:54:00 0 days 08:59:00  1195 2021-07-11 04:54:00 2021-07-11 08:59:00
2 0 days 04:56:00 0 days 10:16:00  1120 2021-07-11 04:56:00 2021-07-11 10:16:00
3 0 days 04:57:00 1 days 01:33:00   204 2021-07-11 04:57:00 2021-07-12 01:33:00
4 0 days 04:57:00 0 days 09:15:00  1182 2021-07-11 04:57:00 2021-07-11 09:15:00
```